# Fake location find my friends

Tags: ios, geolocation

Can I fake location using two phones with find my friends by swapping sim and leaving phone in place ?

Answer (score 1):

**Find my Friends** reveals neither the name nor the type of the device being used to share your location. So you could switch the device being used for location sharing to a different phone logged in to the same iCloud account, or even to an iPad.

To change this:

- On iOS 11: Settings → Your Profile → iCloud → Share My Location → From.
- On iOS 12: Settings → Your Profile → Share My Location → From.

Lots more details on how to block location: [Can my son block me from finding him with my find my iphone app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311341/can-my-son-block-me-from-finding-him-with-my-find-my-iphone-app)